# My new APK update resulted in "APP UPDATE REJECTED" but it still shows as active in production

Tags: google-play, apk, updates

I uploaded an update (0.2.0) to the Google Play Developer Console, and it triggered a security violation. Why did the app move into production anyway?

[image]